# How to wait for ajax call from main Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue-component, vue.js

I currently have VueJS components that makes an ajax call to github like so:

**(Child) component**

```
Vue.http.get('user/repos').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The problem is that I first need to get an access token before I can make this ajax call. This access token is stored in the database so my main Vue component is making the ajax call to set a common header to all ajax calls:

**Main Vue instance**

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = `token ${this.token}`;

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
      token: ''
    },

    created() {
        Vue.http.get('/token').then((response) => {
            this.token = response.data.token;
        }, () => {
            console.log('failed to retrieve the access token for the logged in user.');
        })
    }
});
```

How can I be sure that before running the ajax call from my component that the ajax call to set the 'Authorization' header has been successful?

Comment: setup a `watch` for it?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal so simply. Didn't even think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding this for anyone else who could benefit.

1. Get the token from the API call, add it up in a vuex state variable.
2. Access the same using a getter in the child component, as a computed property or you can pass it on as props or via an event bus but both the ways are not as powerful as using vuex.
3. `watch` over the property, and perform your required action when the token is obtained.

   ```
   // Add this up in the child component

      computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
           token: <name-of-the-getter> // token becomes the alias for the computed
        })                            // property.
      },

      watch: {
        token () {
          if(this.token) this.someAPICall()// or some other applicable condition
        }
      },

      methods: {
        ...mapActions({
          someAPICall: <name-of-the-action>
        })
      }

   // ----------------------------------------------
   ```

Watch requires the value to change, I have noticed that commits made in an action cause the `watch` to trigger. So if for some reason the token is lost, or expires you will naturally not be able to make the subsequent requests.

**EDIT**

```
import store from 'path/to/store'

axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // extract the token from the response object
  // save the token to the store for access during subsequent
  // requests.
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with response error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // use store getters to access token
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Any idea on what to do when there a lot of places that need the token? Repeat the code across all pages or create a route guard?

Comment: I use axios interceptors and store to handle that scenario. Would you like an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace/proxyfiy Vue.http.get function by your own function that will request token first and then do your request, rough idea:

```
!function() 
{ 
  var vue_http_get = Vue.http.get;
  var token = null;

  // patching/proxying Vue.http.get function   
  Vue.http.get = function get() {
    vue_http_get.apply(Vue.http,"path/to/get/token/").then(function(resp){
      token = resp; 
      Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = ...;
      // putting back original Vue.http
      Vue.http = vue_http_get;
      return Vue.http.get(arguments[0]);
    });
  }; 
}();
```